# How to make a standalone installer for Python project which includes Python installation

Tags: python, installation, inno-setup, pyinstaller

I have a Python project which has following directories and files:

```
PythonProject
    -> configs
        -> appconfig.json
    -> logs
        -> applog.log
    -> output
        -> output file1
        -> output file2
    -> src
        -> file1.py
        -> file2.py
        -> file3.py 
    app.py
```

I have `app.py` which is the main starting point of the project. It is depended on Python files in `src` and also depended on `configs`, `logs` and `output` directories.

I want to create an installer for this so that we have `setup.exe` which user can run and all the files and directories and stored somewhere in `Program Files`. This I can do by using `pyinstaller` on `app.py` and rest of the Python files can be converted to binaries. Finally I can use Inno Setup to pack everything and create `setup.exe`.

But the problem is that the whole application is built in Python and the users who are going to use it have no idea about installing Python and its packages. So I am looking for a solution in which I can also pack Python installer so that once a user is installing the software, Python is installed first and then its related Python packages and then finally our project. How can I achieve this? Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: If pyinstaller does not help, you can get an embeddable Python and ship it with your project: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyInstaller includes Python already:
https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html

> Then it collects copies of all those files – **including the active Python interpreter!** – and puts them with your script in a single folder, or optionally in a single executable file.